# Makefile fails with c++ compilation

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
TARGET  =   foobar
CXX     =   g++
CXXFLAGS =  -Wall -I./inc/
LINKER  =   $(CXX) -o
LFLAGS  =   -I./inc/

SRCDIR  =   src
INCDIR  =   inc
OBJDIR  =   obj
BINDIR  =   bin

SOURCES     :=  $(wildcard &(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES    :=  $(wildcard $(INCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS     :=  $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm          =   rm -f

$(info SOURCES [${SOURCES}])
$(info INCLUDES [${SOURCES}])
$(info OBJECTS [${OBJECTS}])

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONE: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) 
    @echo "Exacutable removed!"
```

My folder structure is:

```
src/somesources.cpp
inc/somesources.h
obj/
bin/
Makefile
```

This makefile works flawless with c files, but I'm having problems with c++. Can someone tell the difference between c and c++ and where I'm wrong? The output message I get is:

```
SOURCES []
INCLUDES []
OBJECTS []
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: `&(SRCDIR)` should be `$(SRCDIR)` -- 12th line

Comment: ... here: `SOURCES     :=  $(wildcard &(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)`

Comment: And as for why includes is empty, it's because you're showing the wrong variable: `$(info INCLUDES [${SOURCES}])`

Comment: I'm absolutely stunned how may I be so f**** stupid :( Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
SOURCES     :=  $(wildcard &(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
```

to

```
SOURCES     :=  $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
```

Also,

```
.PHONE: remove
```

should be

```
.PHONY: remove
```